# QGIS simplifying WFS features

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs

I am trying to load features of WFS using pyQGIS.

The preview through GeoServer shows how it should look like

[image]

Now, using the following code :

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setParam('service', 'wfs')
uri.setParam('version', '1.1.0')
uri.setParam('request', 'GetFeature')
uri.setParam('typename', 'myworkspace:all_pipelines')
uri.setParam('srsName', 'EPSG:3857')
uri.setParam('url', 'https://geoserver-dev.myside.io/geoserver/wfs')
```

I get the following representation in QGIS.

[image]

It seems to me that the features are simplified. I am note sure where this change originates from.

Comment: the styling is different but it doesn't look simplified to me (and I doubt that it could happen by accident). Try underlaying the WMS view in QGIS to be sure

Comment: If the source data for GeoServer is PostGIS, make sure to turn off the on-thy-fly simplification.

Comment: the source is Geoserver for PostGIS but I do not see any on-the-fly simplification. Does the flag comes from PostGIS or Geoserver ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to increase the number of decimals in Geoserver global configuration

[image]